# Importing html, js and python file into an express server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I currently have a html that sends a request to another node server, and that node server sends the request to another python file for some operations.

Home.html <--> app.js <--> app.py

What I want to ask is that if I create a server.js and serve the html in there, like

server.js <--> Home.html <--> app.js <--> app.py

would it be a good idea leave the app.js and app.py alone or would I need to make changes to make it more efficient?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "it depends". If you provide your code and describe how you intend to change it, it may help in figuring that out.